# How can I allow dots in mailaddress parameter in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I have the following .htaccess, which works fine except that I can't use the user's emailadress because it contains dots (used a online tool to generate some lines). I the meantime I just replaced `.` by `_`, but I would be more happy to know how I should allow dots. (Yes I saw some other questions regarding this matter, but I don't know how to change it in my .htaccess)

The url has the following format
 `mywebsite.com/tkn/{somerandomstring}/{mail}`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
... Some other rules...
RewriteRule ^tkn/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /reset?tkn=$1&mail=$2 [L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your url end with `.php`?

Comment: well no, only my php files end with `.php`